# If $P \lor Q$ and $\neg P \lor \neg Q$ are both true, do we get a contradiction?

Tags: proof-verification, propositional-calculus

**Question**

If 
$$P \lor Q$$
and
$$\neg P \lor \neg Q$$
are both true, do we get a contradiction?

**My Attempt**

Since
$$\left\{\neg P \lor \neg Q\right\} \Longleftrightarrow \neg \left\{P \land Q\right\}$$
the question essentially asks whether
$$P \lor Q$$
is logically equivalent to
$$P \land Q$$
which I know is not true when e.g., $P$ is **True** and $Q$ is **False**.

My inquiry is that:  Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Hint: What would happen if $P$ and $\lnot Q$ were both true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R \equiv P \lor Q$ and $S \equiv \neg P \lor \neg Q$. When you say "when both $R$ and $S$ are true", you are looking for $R \land S$. If $R \land S$ is always **false** no matter who is $P$ or $Q$, then it is a contradiction, otherwise it is not.

Now, about your reasoning: although your final answer gives the right counter-example, we have:
\begin{align}
R\land S\:\equiv\:&(P \lor Q)\land(\neg P \lor \neg Q)\\
\equiv\:&(P \lor Q)\land\neg( P \land Q)\\
\equiv\:& \neg (\neg(P \lor Q)\lor( P \land Q))\\
\equiv\:& \neg ((P\lor Q)\rightarrow (P\land Q)),
\end{align}
which is different from $(P\lor Q)$ and $(P \land Q)$ being "logically equivalent":
\begin{align}
(P\lor Q)\leftrightarrow (P\land Q) \equiv ((P\lor Q)\rightarrow (P\land Q)) \land ((P\land Q)\rightarrow (P\lor Q)).
\end{align}

---

Solution:

\begin{align}
R\land S\:\equiv\:&(P \lor Q)\land(\neg P \lor \neg Q)\\
\equiv \:& (\neg P\land (P \lor Q))\lor(\neg Q \land (P \lor Q))\\
\equiv \:& (\bot \lor(\neg P\land Q))\lor((\neg Q \land P)\lor \bot)\\
\equiv \:& (\neg P\land Q)\lor(\neg Q \land P),
\end{align}

which is **true** when "$P$ is **true** and $Q$ is **false**" or when "$P$ is **false** and $Q$ is **true**". Therefore is not a contradiction.

---

This is the logical operator [**XOR**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) (exclusive or), and we denote $R\land S \equiv P\oplus Q$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive answer.  This is exactly what I needed!  =)